# Merging two data frames with different sizes by matching their columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to "merge" column V of a Data Frame in another one if the columns X and Y are equals (I have to match `dOne.X == dTwo.X & dOne.Y == dTwo.Y` and also `dOne.X == dTwo.Y & dOne.Y == dTwo.X`)
I solved this using a `for` loop, but it is slow when the Data Frame dOne is big (in my machine it takes 25 minutes if `length(dOne.X) == 500000`). I would like to know if there is a way to solve this problem using a faster "vectorized" operation. Above is an exemple of what I want to do:

```
Data Frame ONE
X Y  V
a b  2
a c  3
a d  0
a e  0
b c  2
b d  3
b e  0
c d  2
c e  0
d e  0

Data Frame TWO
X Y  V
a b  1
a c  1
a d  1
b c  1
b d  1
c d  1
e d  1

Expected Data Frame after the columns are merged
X Y  V V2
a b  2  1
a c  3  1
a d  0  1
a e  0  0
b c  2  1
b d  3  1
b e  0  0
c d  2  1
c e  0  0
d e  0  1
```

This is the code I am using so far that is slow when dOne is big (hundreds of thousands or rows):

```
copyadjlistValueColumn <- function(dOne, dTwo) {
    dOne$V2 <- 0

    lv <- union(levels(dOne$Y), levels(dOne$X))

    dTwo$X <- factor(dTwo$X, levels = lv)
    dTwo$Y <- factor(dTwo$Y, levels = lv)
    dOne$X <- factor(dOne$X, levels = lv)
    dOne$Y <- factor(dOne$Y, levels = lv)

    for(i in 1:nrow(dTwo)) {
      row <- dTwo[i,]
      dOne$V2[dOne$X == row$X & dOne$Y == row$Y] <- row$V
      dOne$V2[dOne$X == row$Y & dOne$Y == row$X] <- row$V
    }
    dOne
}
```

This is a testthat test case that covers what I am expecting (using the data frames above):

```
test_that("Copy V column to another Data Frame", {
    dfOne <- data.frame(X=c("a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "d"),
                        Y=c("b", "c", "d", "e", "c", "d", "e", "d", "e", "e"),
                        V=c(2, 3, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 2, 0, 0))

    dfTwo <- data.frame(X=c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "e"),
                        Y=c("b", "c", "d", "c", "d", "d", "d"),
                        V=c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1))

    lv <- union(levels(dfTwo$Y), levels(dfTwo$X))
    dfExpected <- data.frame(X=c("a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "d"),
                             Y=c("b", "c", "d", "e", "c", "d", "e", "d", "e", "e"),
                             V=c(2, 3, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 2, 0, 0),
                             V2=c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1))
    dfExpected$X <- factor(dfExpected$X, levels = lv)
    dfExpected$Y <- factor(dfExpected$Y, levels = lv)

    dfMerged <- copyadjlistValueColumn(dfOne, dfTwo)

    expect_identical(dfMerged, dfExpected)
})
```

Any suggestion?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to join data frames in R (inner, outer, left, right)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-data-frames-in-r-inner-outer-left-right)

Comment: What about `merge(dOne, dTwo, by = c("X", "Y"), all.x = TRUE)`? Though it is not exactly match your desired output for some reason

Comment: Hey David, I think it is because I have to match it in a "bidirectional" way: `dOne.X == dTwo.X & dOne.Y == dTwo.Y` and also `dOne.X == dTwo.Y & dOne.Y == dTwo.X`

Comment: This is *NOT* a duplicate of the linked question, so unless you have an alternative link, don't close this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try two `merge`, where order of matching columns is reversed in the second, to get the 'bidirectional' matching. Then you may use e.g. `rowSums` to collapse the two created columns to one.

```
d1 <- merge(dfOne, dfTwo, by.x = c("X", "Y"), by.y = c("X", "Y"), all.x = TRUE)
d2 <- merge(d1, dfTwo, by.x = c("X", "Y"), by.y = c("Y", "X"), all.x = TRUE)
cbind(dfOne, V2 = rowSums(cbind(d2$V.y, d2$V), na.rm = TRUE))


#    X Y V V2
# 1  a b 2  1
# 2  a c 3  1
# 3  a d 0  1
# 4  a e 0  0
# 5  b c 2  1
# 6  b d 3  1
# 7  b e 0  0
# 8  c d 2  1
# 9  c e 0  0
# 10 d e 0  1
```

For faster alternatives to `merge`, check `data.table` and `dplyr` alternatives here: stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-data-frames-in-r-inner-outer-left-right/

Comment: @alf., Please note that I made a tiny change to get rid of the re`name` in the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a possible `data.table` package approach. This approach should be particularly efficient for a big data set like you have:

First convert to `data.table` object and add keys

```
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(dfOne), X, Y)
setkey(setDT(dfTwo), X, Y)
```

Then perform a join on `X & Y` combination - the join is performed by matching key columns `X,Y` of `dfOne` with key columns `X,Y` of `dfTwo` respectively.

```
dfOne[dfTwo, V2 := i.V]
```

Now perform a join on `Y & X` combination - the join is performed by matching key columns `X,Y` of `dfOne` with key columns `Y,X` of `dfTwo` respectively.

```
setkey(dfTwo, Y, X)
dfOne[dfTwo, V2 := i.V][]
```

Result (I'll keep the unmatched as `NA`s instead of zeroes as it makes more sense this way):

```
#     X Y V V2
#  1: a b 2  1
#  2: a c 3  1
#  3: a d 0  1
#  4: a e 0 NA
#  5: b c 2  1
#  6: b d 3  1
#  7: b e 0 NA
#  8: c d 2  1
#  9: c e 0 NA
# 10: d e 0  1
```

Comment: @alf. Have you tried this approach? Didn't get any feedback from you.

Answer (score 2):

With `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

left_join(dfOne, dfTwo, by = c("X", "Y")) %>% 
  left_join(dfTwo, by = c("X" = "Y", "Y" = "X")) %>% 
  mutate(V2 = ifelse(is.na(V.y), V, V.y)) %>% 
  select(X, Y, V = V.x, V2) %>% 
  do(replace(., is.na(.), 0))
```

Comment: Thanks junkka! I will stick with Henrik answer as it is easier to understand.